# How to time scala map functions in an aggregative fashion?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, timing

I am having a hard to come up with a solution to time individual functions in a Scala map operation. Let's say I have the following line in my code:

```
 val foo = data.map(d => func1(d).func2())
```

where `data` is a Seq of *N* elements. How would I go about timing how long my program has executed `func1` in total and `func2` in total? Since it is a map operation, these functions will be called *N* times, so each time record should be added to a cumulative time record.

How can I do this without breaking the Scala syntax?

NB: I want to end up with `totalTime_inFunc1` and `totalTime_inFunc2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say, `func2()` returns `YourType`. Then, you need to return tuple `(YourType, Long, Long)` from function inside `map`, where second tuple element is execution time of func1 and third element is exec time of func2. After that, you can easily get execution time from seq of tuples using sum:

```
val fooWithTime = {
  data.map(d => {
    def now = System.currentTimeMillis
    val beforeFunc1 = now
    val func1Result = func1(d)
    val func1Time = now - beforeFunc1
    val beforeFun2 = now
    val result = func1Result.func2()
    (result, func1Time, now - beforeFun2)
  }
}
val foo = fooWithTime.map(_._1)
val totalTimeFunc1 = fooWithTime.map(_._2).sum
val totalTimeFunc2 = fooWithTime.map(_._3).sum
```

Also, you can easily use your preferred method of calculating execution time instead of `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

Comment: Hah, I literally just wrote that and was about to post it. BTW you have a typo `withTime` instead of `fooWithTime`. +1

Comment: Thanks this seems like the easiest solution. If I wanted to time the functions individually (see edited question), then I would just do the same thing, but split the `result` into two parts, and measure each of them right?

Comment: @JimmyJumbo right, edited answer according to your question change.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [Closure](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-use-closures-in-scala-fp-examples). You will declare your functions and make them refer to variable in scope, then pass them to map, and make them increment variable from scope.

## Edit

code with closures

```
object closure {

  var time1 = 0L
  var time2 = 0L

  def time[R](block: => R)(time: Int): R = {
    val t0 = System.nanoTime()
    val result = block    // call-by-name
    val t1 = System.nanoTime()
    if (time==1)
    time1 += t1-t0
    else
    time2 += t1-t0
    result
  }

  def fun1(i: Int): Int = {
    time{i+1}(1)
  }

  def fun2(i: Int): Int = {
    time{i+2}(2)
  }

}

val data = List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,5,6,7)

val foo = data.map(d => closure.fun2(closure.fun1(d)))

closure.time1 // res4: Long = 22976
closure.time2 // res5: Long = 25438
```

## Edit 2

```
object closure {

  var time1 = 0L
  var time2 = 0L

  def time[R](block: => R)(time: Int): R = {
    val t0 = System.nanoTime()
    val result = block    // call-by-name
    val t1 = System.nanoTime()
    if (time==1)
    time1 += t1-t0
    else
    time2 += t1-t0
    result
  }

  val data = List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,5,6,7)

  val test = new test;

  val foo = data.map(d => {
    val fun1 = time{test.fun1(d)}(1)
    time{fun1.fun2(d)}(2)
  })

}
```

Comment: This is a nice solution if I could define my functions separately like that. I should have mentioned in the question, but the functions in question are part of a large library. Isolating them would require change in the dependency structure. I will remember this for future (smaller) projects!

Comment: @JimmyJumbo i've added code which should meets your needs :)

Answer (score 0):

```
val s = Seq(1, 2, 3)

val (mappedSeq, totalTime) = s.map(x => {
  // call your map methods here and time
  // x is the mapped element
  val timing = 5.5
  // then return the tuple with mapped element and time taken for the map function
  (x, timing)
}).foldLeft((Seq.empty[Int], 0d))((accumulator, pair) => (accumulator._1 :+ pair._1, accumulator._2 + pair._2))

println(totalTime)
println(mappedSeq.mkString(", "))
```